Writing Chidushei Torah Immediately
In the recently published biography of the Klausenburger Rebbe a story is being told about a time in which the Rebbe rushed while he was  davening to have a chidush he had, written.
Given that the Rebbe would never interrupt davening, even for Torah learning he explained that because of his advanced age he at times cannot focus enough in order to hold back Torah thoughts while davening.
That is why he rushed to have the chiddush written down - in order to follow the Sefer Chasidim that says that an every chiddush Torah a person has he must write down immediately before he forgets it.
I am looking for the exact place in the Sefer Chassidim where this is brought down.

Seemingly, he's referring to section #530:

וכל מי שגלה לו הקב"ה דבר ואינו כותבה ויכול לכתוב הרי גוזל מי שגלה לו
כי לא גלו לו אלא לכתוב דכתיב (תהלים כה יד) סוד ה' ליראיו ובריתו
להודיעם וכתיב (משלי ה טז) יפוצו מעינותיך חוצה וזהו שכתוב (קהלת יב יד)
יביא במשפט על כל נעלם שגורם שנעלם אם טוב שגילה לו אם רע שאינו כתבה.


Based on that the book is wrong in saying that the point of writing is so that not to forget it.

@Yoreinu That is correct. Otherwise, it would be forbidden to write down the Oral Torah.
